# How to check if my app is in visible background if it calls another application activity on android

Tags: android

My application launches activity of another application (sms, e-mail or another...). How do I know if my application is still in focus? Whether the user has minimized it? Was it overlapped by another application (not called from my application)?

Comment: If another application is in focus , your's is definitely in the background.

Comment: If I launch an activity of another application from my own, it is not launched in a new task, which means that my application does not go into the background, and only my activity goes into the background. Is not it?

Comment: When another applicatiion is launched not just your activity but your whole application goes into background.

Comment: That is, there is no way to find out? I am actually launching an activity of another application using   startActivityForResult()    to get data from another application. At the same time, I want to know if the user has minimized the application (if he is still in the activity I need).

onPause() can be triggered when I launch an activity I need, as well as when the user simply minimizes the application.

Answer (score 0):

[image: The activity lifecycle]

Detailed Description : [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

The ACTIVTY Lifecycle describes all the states your activity can be right from when your app is started till when it is destroyed(maybe by the user after clearing from recents menu in modern phones or is killed by the system due to lack of resources)
This short image with descriptions will help you understand which method is called exactly when and is also open to you experimenting.

So in your case as to when to detect when another activity is in focus, it is when the `onPause` method of your activity is called but I recommend going through all the other methods

Comment: I want to know if my application has focus, that is, if any activity has focus (including another aplication activity called from my application)

the onPause method can be called when the user minimizes the application, and when minimized, the application does not have focus (all activityes have no focus)